# IllegalLocatorException - Selenium Web Driver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

Ok I am writing a simple code in Selenium Web Driver. What it does is:

1. Open URL Google.com
2. Enter 'abc' in search bar
3. Click the Images tab

I am using windows 8 - 64 bit and Visual Studio 2013. Browser is Firefox.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;

namespace WebDriverDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.Url = "http://google.com";

            var searchBox = driver.FindElement(By.Id("gbqfq"));
            searchBox.SendKeys("abc");

            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));

            var images = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("q qs"))[0];
            images.Click();

        }
    }
}
```

But I am getting an exception on the second last line of the code. Here is the exception:

[image]

Here is the Inspect Element result:

[image]

Comment: Can't really see the `html` can provide the `html` not the image

Comment: Sorry I did not get your point.

Comment: The `exception` window and the `F12` both are so blurred cannot see what's there. However, I guess I pointed out your issue in my answer.

Comment: Just right click and open the image in new tab, it will be clear there :)

Comment: Ya. ended up doing that earlier. However, I think the question was answered and also the updated part as well. You need to use `cssSelector` and with `.q.qs` as I stated in all the answers. You are missing `.` before each class

Comment: Let me test that for you real quick.

Comment: You are missing `driver.FindElement(By.Name("btnG")).Click();` after the `searchBox.SendKeys("abc");`. See the update on my answer.

Comment: Yes it did the miracle. But please tell me that I am using a tutorial. In which the person wrote the same code and it's working there. How? Also please add this comment in answer so that I mark it as accepted.

Comment: I have no clue how that should work without that line unless that guys has some magic :). My answer is updated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And, the issue is compound class. Currently `selenium` does not support this. You can use the `cssSelector` on the other hand to avoid this issue.

```
.q.qs
```

Note `.` before each class and see my answer related to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519172/not-able-to-click-on-remove-button-in-modal-window-using-selenium-webdriverja/28529202#28529202)

**Complete code as per OP's update:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;

namespace WebDriverDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.Url = "http://google.com";

            var searchBox = driver.FindElement(By.Id("gbqfq"));
            searchBox.SendKeys("abc");
            //The following line is missing that is mandatory.
            driver.FindElement(By.Name("btnG")).Click();

            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));

            var images = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".q.qs"))[0];
            images.Click();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The exception message tells you exactly what the problem is. You cannot use multiple, or "compound," class names when using `By.ClassName`. A single class name cannot contain a space. If you want to use multiple class names, use `By.CssSelector`.

Comment: Agree. Seems like a common issue

Comment: But Google has written the same way like class='q qa'. Please tell me that wherever I have the class name having a space, I should use CSS Selector there?

Comment: I used this line of code: var images = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".q.qs"));   and I got this exception: An unhandled exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException' occurred in WebDriver.dll

Answer (score 0):

Using CSSSelector:

```
 var images = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".q.qs"));
 images.Click();
```

Using LinkText :

```
 var images = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Images"));
 images.Click();
```

Using Xpath :

```
  var images = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='q qs' and .='Images']"));
  images.Click();
```

Comment: Using the first line of code, i.e. using CssSelector, I got another exception: An unhandled exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException' occurred in WebDriver.dll